# C# OracleCommand.ExecuteArrray(int) does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, visual-studio

I am currently working on a C# application which interacts with an Oracle Database.

In some cases we cannot use the BulkCopy. In those cases, we used to insert one line at a time the data. We found out about the ArrayBind posibility recently, and I have been put in charge of implementing it.

In that tutorial (https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/arraybind.html) everything i need to use it properly is explained. Unfortunately, I am stuck on the very last step. my cmd object (OracleCommand type) does not have an ExecuteArray(int) method.

Basically, everything works except that visual studio does not recognize ExecuteArray as a valid method or function name. Therefore it obviously does not compile.

Obviously, All the types used in the tutorial (OracleConnection, OracleCommand, etc) are recognized, so I don't think it's a missing reference or "using" problem.

My question is: How do I solve this problem, and if I can't because of some version problem (we can't update the DLLs without going through a several month-long procedure), is there a work around that will allow me to do some arraybinding inserts?

Comment: I have no oracle but the [documentation](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand~ExecuteArray.html) mentions _"Supported only for Oracle 12c Release 1 (12.1) - both server and client"_

Comment: What namespace is your `OracleCommand` from? There are at least two (MS and ODP) and I guess dotConnect has their own?

Comment: It is Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand